# Не могу понять, как перебрать свой JSON ( JS )

Tags: javascript, json

Принимаю JSON:

```
{"data":[{"name":"Alex","age":"21","karma":"99","email":"sineadharkin@gumaygo.com"},{"name":"Elvira","age":"21","karma":"75","email":"blank909@yt-google.com"},{"name":"Keitha","age":"21","karma":"13","email":"scarydog@ezybarber.com"},{"name":"Michaela","age":"41","karma":"1","email":"karovero@ameliachoi.com"},{"name":"Chevrolet","age":"38","karma":"25","email":"byqanixi@afractalreality.com"},{"name":"Ilona","age":"38","karma":"100","email":"rastex4@automizly.net"},{"name":"Alex","age":"41","karma":"45","email":"daryarodnaya@elderflame.xyz"}]}
```

Мне его нужно распарсить и данные каждого пользователя записать в отдельные строки. Вот таким хитрым способом убрал data: `let a = array.data;` , но как его перебрать я не знаю...
Пытался перебрать и так:

```
a.forEach((element) => {
element.forEach((data) => {
    document.getElementById("usersList").value = data;
});});
```

Пытался так:

```
for(let i in a) {
  document.getElementById("usersList").value += a[i];
}
```

Comment: Как и во всех языках программирования - циклом. Изучали циклы?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Да, изучал. Но проблема в том, что как бы я не перебирал код, получаю либо [object object], либо не совсем то что мне нужно. Пытался перебрать for...in-ом и forEach-ом

Comment: покажите все попытки и весь код и что с ним где было не так..... правьте вопрос, добавляйте все попытки и все проблемы

Comment: Исправьте ваш вопрос. Добавьте JSON текстом и вашу попытку его перебрать. + желаемый результат

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Правил вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Каждый `element` - это объект. Данные объекта, в зависимости от цели, берутся либо методом `Object.keys()` либо `Object.values()`  либо `Object.entries()`. Все они будут давать каки-либо массивы и можно уже по результатам выполнения этих функция проходится циклом. Однако в текущем случае этого не особо и надо, т.к., `element` - это отдельный объект, то достаточно обращаться к свойству объекта через точку или квадратные скобки... т.е. либо

```
console.log(element.name);
```

либо

```
console.log(element['name']);
```

В итоге второй цикл на данный момент тут просто не нужен

---

для `for...in`  тоже самое... только вместо `element` тут `a[i]`. После `a[i]`  должна быть либо точка и имя свойства объекта, либо ещё одни квадратные скобки и имя свойства в них

Comment: Спасибо большое. Начал редактировать код, когда сюда писал вопрос и понял в чем была загвоздка.
Посмотрел под другим ракурсом, так сказать)))